# scanf does not ask for input

Tags: c, xcode, scanf

It takes a lot of time to compile, and some random number shows up, apparently the `scanf()` doesn't ask for the input

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a;
    //a =  1472464;
    scanf ("%d", &a);
        if ((a % 6) && (a %4) == 0)
        {
            printf("Input %d is divisible by 6 and 4\n", a);
        }
        else {
            printf(" Input %d is not divisible by 6 and 4\n", a);
        }
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this piece of code shouldn't require a lot of time to compile...

Comment: @Raptor: I don't think you should have deleted the [tag:xcode] tag - apart from the obvious bug there might be an issue with stdin input in the Xcode console.

Comment: alright, added back, but I don't think this is Xcode-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
    if ((a % 6) && (a %4) == 0)
```

It should be:

```
    if ((a % 6) == 0 && (a %4) == 0)
```

[I don't see any other obvious problem with the code.](http://ideone.com/jyT2dE)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(a % 6) && (a %4) == 0` does not compare both modulo-operations with zero. Instead it does `(a % 6)` which will result on a number between `0` and `5`, and use that as a boolean value that it then uses with the result of `(a %4) == 0`.

Instead you need to do each comparison separately: `(a % 6) == 0 && (a % 4) == 0`

---

The important thing to know here is that in C only zero and a null pointer is considered "false". Anything that is not zero (or a null pointer) is true.

That means that if `a` for example is `4` then `a % 6` will be "true" since `a % 6` is `4` which is not zero. Conversely when `a` is for example `6` then `a % 6` will be `0` which is "false".

So using only `a % 6` will actually give the opposite result to what you want, it will be "true" when `a` is *not* evenly dividable by `6`.